# JQ click() event wont bind to a button

Tags: jquery, onclick, click

I have a function running on a page generating buttons according to a specific
set of rules.  The problem start's when I try to get the buttons and bind a click event on to them. 
This is how I process my buttons:

```
function button_Func(user, friend) {
  var action = "";
  var buttons = $("button");
  buttons.each(function() {
    var button = this;
    switch ($(this).val()) {
      case 'addFriend': 
        action = "add_Friend";
        friend_Stat(button, user, friend, action);
        break;
      case 'approve': 
        action = "approve_friend";
        break;
      case 'decline': 
        action = "not_Friend";
        friend_Stat(button, user, friend, action);
        break;
      case 'unfriend': 
        action = "de_Friend";
        friend_Stat(button, user, friend, action);
        break;
      case 'regret': 
        action = "update_Friend";
        friend_Stat(button, user, friend, action);
        break;
      case 'regret_request': 
        action = "de_Friend";
        friend_Stat(button, user, friend, action);
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }

  });
}
```

As i said, this works but the bind part dose not:

```
function friend_Stat(button, user, friend, action) 
  {
    button.click(function() {
      $.post('ajax.php', {
          user_id: user,
          friend: friend,
          ajax: action
        },
        function(data) {
          if (!data) {
            $('#errPopup').html(data);
          } else location.reload(true);
        }
      );
    });
  }
```

I tried everything I can think of and I keep running this with no success of any key bind...

Comment: Have you tried `on()`'s event delegation syntax?

Comment: I have,,, it didn't work...

Comment: I think the button element you are passing in is a JavaScript object as opposed to the jQuery object so you can't call button.click(). What happens if you write var button = $(this);

Comment: Thank you! that was it! All I needed to do was "var button = $(button)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing in the JavaScript DOM Button object so you cannot call jQuery methods on it. You need to write `var button = $(this);` and then you can call button.click();